# Should forms be validated by javascript before submiting?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am wondering if it is necessary to validate data with javascript before submiting a form. If someone wants to be clever, he can disable javascript in a browser so it becomes useless. How do you think? Is server-side validation sufficient?

Comment: It should be validated at both frontend ( only some of the values which has some rules to be valid or pattern to followed is necessary ) and backend ( all the values ),

Comment: Client-side validation is for convenience only.

Comment: @RobG it also reduces server load by filtering out data transfers that do not meet to requirements. In this way the server does not need to process those.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side validation is necessary but not sufficient.
client-side validation helps to reduce invalid requests to the server and help the user to get it right sooner and easier.

Comment: _"Server-side validation is necessary but **not sufficient**_ ? Are you sure you didn't mean that Client-side validation is not sufficient?

Comment: @AlonEitan I think the argument is that server side is necessary for security, but insufficient because of the user experience.

Comment: @JaredSmith Oh, that does make much more sense

Comment: @JaredSmith—server validation is not just (or even primarily) for security, it's to ensure valid data. ;-)

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your goal is.

Server side validation is mostly done to prevent unwanted data to be processed by your server.

Client side validation is often done to provide a better user experience and reduce the amount of invalid data transfers to the server.

Both have a completely different goal in mind. The first is aimed at security and the second at user experience.

Answer (score 0):

**Never trust data passed to your server from the client. Even if your form is validating correctly and preventing malformed input, a malicious user can still alter the network request.**

- from MDN and any decent programing site out there...